# Can I bring my palm tree/plant back to life?

Tags: plant-health, palm

All of the leaves are dead, but the stems (and I assume the roots) are still intact. What can I do (if there's anything at all) to revive my plant baby?[image]

Comment: Do you know exactly what plant it was? Was it  actually a palm of some sort?

Comment: Yes it was a palm tree/plant

Answer (score 1):

The whole plant appears to be an ex plant, dead in other words; if it was a palm, then its definitely dead, because the central growing point is also dead. However,I can't see if there's anything green at the top of the thicker, taller stem, but if there's no  green anywhere, it would appear it needs a decent burial I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

There's no green, no sign of life at all. Sorry, Caitlin, I think its time for a new palm.